# change values of declaration variables in jsp scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, variables, declaration

Is that possible to change a variable's value from declaration jsp in scriptlet?
for example my code here doesn't change myV to b. Thanks.

```
<%!
public static class myC{
public static String myV="a";
}
%>
<%
myC.myV="b";
%>
```

Comment: Try using   myC.myV = "b";

Comment: thanks, but actually it's a typo, i should edit that and i still have the problem.

Comment: Your code worked for me.  How did you test? I used <%=myC.myV%>